# How to create an array of functions into Javascript namespace script

Tags: javascript, arrays, namespaces, function-pointers, undefined

I am trying to use an array of functions into my script. 
I use namespacing object and when I use this array,  all my functions are `undefined`.

How to create this array with good functions references to process this `processAllFunction` ?

See my code :

```
var myns = myns || {};
myns.test = myns.test || {};
myns.test.util = {
    myOne: function(m) {
        return m;
    },
    myTwo: function(m) {
        return m;
    },
    processAllFunction: function(m) {
        for(var i=0; i<this.replaceFilters.length; i++) {
            if(typeof(this.replaceFilters[i])==='function') {
            m= this.replaceFilters[i](m);
        }
        }
        console.log(this.replaceFilters); // undefined functions
        return m;
    },
    replaceFilters: [this.myOne, this.myTwo]
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, use replaceFilters outside from object (after declaration).

```
myns.test.util = {
    myOne: function(m) {
        return m;
    },
    myTwo: function(m) {
        return m;
    },
    processAllFunction: function(m) {
        for(var i=0; i<this.replaceFilters.length; i++) {
            if(typeof(this.replaceFilters[i])==='function') {
            m= this.replaceFilters[i](m);
        }
        }
        console.log(this.replaceFilters);
        return m;
    }
};
myns.test.util.replaceFilters = [this.myOne, this.myTwo];
```

with this method, I don't have problem with `this`.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, `this` either refers to `window` or to the value of `this` in the scope of the function where you're defining `myns`, which is why you're seeing `undefined`. What you need is a reference to the calling object. You should be able to do it with something like this:

```
var myns = myns || {};
myns.test = myns.test || {};
myns.test.util = {
    myOne: function(m) {
        return m;
    },
    myTwo: function(m) {
        return m;
    },
    processAllFunction: function(m) {
        for(var i = 0; i < this.getReplaceFilters().length; i++) {
            if(typeof(this.getReplaceFilters()[i]) === 'function') {
               m= this.replaceFilters[i](m);
            }
        }
        return m;
    },
    getReplaceFilters: function() {
        return [this.myOne, this.myTwo];
    }    
};
```

Notice that instead of `replaceFilters` simply having the value `[this.myOne, this.myTwo]`, it is now a function that returns `[this.myOne, this.myTwo]`. This is because when you now call `myns.test.util.getReplaceFilters`, `this` points to `my.test.util`. The same thing happens to `this` when you call `myns.test.util.processAllFunction()`; `this` is again set to `myns.test.util`. It is this value of `this` that is also used when you call `getReplaceFilters` inside `processAllFunction`.

Comment: Thanks for `this` explaination, But I cannot modify my filters outside from class/namespace with this method...